# JavaScript Regex (replace) if absence of word after other word

Tags: javascript, regex, string

Imagine I have the following string:

```
b(hello world)b
```

Now I want to turn the `b(`into a `b(<b>`, but only, if there is no `<b>`already added. This is what I got so far:

```
var string = "abc b(yolo)b cba";   
string.replace("b\((?!<b>)", "b(<b>");
```

Unfortunately I've never used Regex statements before, so I have like no idea what I'm doing, and it's not working...

So, if you understand my problem please provide the answer, and maybe explain how you seeked for a `b(` that is not followed by a `<b>`, because this is the main difficulty here.

Comment: and do you want the `)b` to be a closing tag?

Comment: Later, yes. But If I know how to manage the b( I can do the other one myself...

Comment: @4castle Ah, yes thx. Still doesn't work though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this:

`string.replace(/b\((?!<b>)/g, 'b(<b>')`

You were on the right track, but a string is not a valid regex in javascript, and negative lookahead is `?!` not `!?`

**Edit - your followup question**

You would need a negative lookbehind to first check if the `</b>` comes before the `)b`. Javascript regex engine does not support lookbehind, but you can achieve this with a callback instead:

```
string.replace(/(<\/b>)?\)b/g, (m, c) => c ? m : `</b>${m}`)
```

or if es6 is not supported

```
string.replace(/(<\/b>)?\)b/g, function (m, c) {
 return c ? m : '</b>' + m
})
```

Comment: Thank you, it works :) [Just replace sting with string :P]

Comment: :) this is what I get for posting without testing

Comment: Now, why does this thing not work? :D `.replace(/(?!<\/b>)\)b/g, "</b>)b");`